# Retrieving a value and displaying it in a select option box in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a stored value from database and show it in a select option box. My problem is it's showing the first value as selected. my code is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM bookwizard.book_inventory where bi_SKU='$SKU'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    $bid=($row{'bi_bookcondition_id'});
}

<select class='form-control' id='condition' name='condition'>
    <option value='' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '' ) echo 'selected = 'selected'; ?> </option>      
    <option value='1' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '1')  echo 'selected = 'selected'; ?>Good</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '2')  echo 'selected = 'selected'; ?>Old</option>
    <option value='3' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '3')  echo 'selected = 'selected'; ?>Bad</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: print the output of `$bid`.

Comment: Printed the value of $bid and its coming correctly. But not working with the code.

Comment: Don't use PHP's insecure and long-since deprecated mysql_API

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to close the options. As well as `if` conditions are having error.

Replace your selectbox code as below :

```
<select class='form-control' id='condition' name='condition'>
    <option value='' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '' ) echo "selected = 'selected'"; ?>></option>
    <option value='1' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '1')  echo "selected = 'selected'"; ?>>Good</option>
    <option value='2' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '2')  echo "selected = 'selected'"; ?>>Old</option>
    <option value='3' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '3')  echo "selected = 'selected'"; ?>>Bad</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$query = "SELECT * FROM bookwizard.book_inventory where bi_SKU='$SKU'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
        $bid=($row{'bi_bookcondition_id'});
    ?>
    <select class='form-control' id='condition' name='condition'>
        <option value='' <?php if(!empty($bid) && $bid == '' ){echo 'selected=selected';}?> ></option>      
        <option value='1' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '1'){echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Good</option>
        <option value='2' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '2'){ echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Old</option>
        <option value='3' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '3'){ echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Bad</option>
    </select>
<?php }?>
```

use this select option.

Comment: my problem is, it's not changing according to the value of $bid, so every time the select box is blank. But I want to show the description based on value.

Comment: are you generating multiple select box??

Comment: yes Santosh Patel... I have used.... yes I am generating multiple select box, but with diffrent names.

Comment: what is the value in $bid

Comment: use the updated code again if you have more than one value in &bid

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your code with this :

 <?php    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bookwizard.book_inventory where bi_SKU='$SKU'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {
            $bid=($row{'bi_bookcondition_id'});
        ?>



    <select class='form-control' id='condition' name='condition'>
            <option value='' <?php if(!empty($bid) && $bid == '' ){echo 'selected=selected';}?> ></option>      
            <option value='1' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '1'){echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Good</option>
            <option value='2' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '2'){ echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Old</option>
            <option value='3' <?php if (!empty($bid) && $bid == '3'){ echo 'selected=selected';} ?>>Bad</option>
        </select>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.